# Lua 5.2: Upvalue persistence in dumped functions, problematic due to _ENV upvalue shifting indexes

Tags: lua

I know functions with upvalues aren't officially supported to be dumped and persisted, but it works. And in Lua versions above 5.2, you can manually set each upvalue with `debug.setupvalue` and the resultant function will work fine. I've been experimenting with this for a little while and I cannot expand Lua 5.2 support because the `_ENV` upvalue needs to be manually inserted as the first upvalue, which disrupts the hardcoded indexes of the other upvalues inside the bytecode.

Here's a working example of this problem:

```lua
local u1, u2, u3 = 1, 2, 3
local function upvalues(fn, upvals)
    local setupvalue = (debug or {}).setupvalue
    if setupvalue then
        setupvalue(fn, 1, _ENV)
        for key, value in ipairs(upvals) do
            setupvalue(fn, key + 1, value)
        end
        return fn
    else
        return fn
    end
end

local dump = load(string.dump(function() return u1, u2, u3 end))
dump = upvalues(dump, { 1, 2, 3 })
print(dump())
```

We expect `1, 2, 3` return, but we get `table, 2, 3` because the first upvalue index has been changed to `_ENV` instead of the number 1.

I want to know if there's a way to work with or around this behavior in Lua 5.2. The `debug.upvaluejoin` looks interesting to me but I am very unfamiliar with it and haven't been able to get a working example of it for a while. I mean, even differences from `upvalues` function implementation to manually modifying the textual bytecode is something I'd like to learn about.

EDIT: It's not clear in my original post that I receive these functions dynamically, so I can't quite edit their content during runtime.

Comment: It works if you make sure that the function being dumped has _ENV as an upvalue. Adding `local _=_ENV` does the trick.

Comment: @lhf That makes sense to me. On one side note, I do get these functions from a user and they're dynamically dumped. I should edit my post to specify this. Worst case scenario I can advise people on Lua 5.2 to include this.

Comment: @wellinthatcase if your functions don't use the `_ENV`, you don't need to set it. Just iterate over the upvalues using `debug.getupvalue` to see whether the function needs `_ENV` in the first place.

Comment: @LMD I will remember that.

Comment: Please note that _ENV upvalue (if it exists) is not always the first upvalue of a function.  Sometimes you might need `setupvalue(fn, 2, _ENV)`.  Users should not only dump their functions but also determine the upvalue index of _ENV if it exists in the function.

Comment: When is _ENV the second upvalue?